# radio butons no funcionan react

Tags: reactjs

Tengo unos redio buttons que no funcionan correctamente

```
<div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="agen" id="agen"  onChange={this.handleChange} value="1" />
                        <label className="col-sm-5 col-form-label" >{this.state.lng["0"]["payTble"]["agen"]}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="huesped" id="huesped" onChange={this.handleChange} value="2"/>
                        <label className="col-sm-5 col-form-label">{this.state.lng["0"]["payTble"]["huesped"]}</label>
                    </div>
```

y en la siguiente funcion seteo el valor

```
handleChange(checked) {
        console.log("checked",checked.target.value);
        this.setState({isCorp : checked.target.value}); 
    }
```

Mi problema es que no funcionan los radio butons puedo seleccionar los dos al mismo tiempo y ya no se puede des-seleccionar

Answer (score 0):

Te falta decirle al `input` si debe estar checkeado o no con el atributo `checked={ bool }`, usando el estado `isCorp` para saber a cuál ponerle `true`. Además, ambos `input` deben tener el mismo atributo `name`.

A parte de esto, he corregido:

- `class` es una palabra con significado especial en Javascript (para declarar clases). El atributo para añadir una clase CSS es `className`.
- El componente `label` puede contener ambos el `input` y el texto relacionado. Otra forma de usarlo es añadir al componente `label` el atributo `for="id"`, donde `id` es el `id` del `input` al que pertenece.

```javascript
class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {isCorp: ""};
  handleChange(checked) {
        console.log("checked",checked.target.value);
        this.setState({isCorp : checked.target.value}); 
   }
  render() {
    const {isCorp} = this.state;
    return <div>
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <label className="col-sm-5 col-form-label" >
                          <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="check" aria-checked={ isCorp === "1" } onChange={this.handleChange} value="1" />
                          {"Value 1"}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <label className="col-sm-5 col-form-label">
                          <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="check" aria-checked={ isCorp === "2" } onChange={this.handleChange} value="2"/>
                          {"Value 2"}
                        </label>
                    </div>
    </div>;
  }
}
```